# In C++11, is "lambda function" same with "lambda expression" and "closure"?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures, evaluation

On cppreference website，when talking about direct_initialization, it says it works in closure parameter capture like...{...} 
I think this should be "lambda function", but why it's also called "closure"?

I checked C++11 standard, the item "closure" first appeared in section 5.1.2 (lambda expression)，which says:

```
The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary (12.2). This temporary is called the 
closure object. A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand (Clause 5). [ Note: A 
closure object behaves like a function object (20.8). — end note ]
```

So how to understand "evalute lamdba expression"? It this "evaluation" something happened during compilation or runtime?
Is there differences in C++11, among the items "lambda expression", "lambda function", and "closure"?

I'm not talking about other programming languages like Closure, just focus on C++11.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is a closure** (quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Function_objects_.28C.2B.2B.29)):

> In programming languages, closures (also lexical closures or function
>   closures) are a technique for implementing lexically scoped name
>   binding in languages with first-class functions. **Operationally, a
>   closure is a record storing a function<sup>[a]</sup> together with an
>   environment**: a mapping associating each free variable of
>   the function (variables that are used locally, but defined in an
>   enclosing scope) with the value or storage location to which the name
>   was bound when the closure was created<sup>[b]</sup>. A closure,
>   unlike a plain function, allows the function to access those captured
>   variables through the closure's reference to them, even when the
>   function is invoked outside their scope.
>
> <sub>[a] *The function may be stored as a reference to a function,
>   such as a function pointer.*</sub>
>
> <sub>[b] *These names most frequently refer to values, mutable
>   variables, or functions, but can also be other entities such as
>   constants, types, classes, or labels.*</sub>

**What is a lambda expression** (quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29)):

> In computer programming, an *anonymous function* (function literal,
>   lambda abstraction) is a function definition that is not bound to an
>   identifier.
>
> Since C++11, C++ supports *anonymous functions*, called *lambda
>   expressions*, which have the form:
>
> ```
> [capture](parameters) -> return_type { function_body }
> ```
>
> An example lambda function is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> [](int x, int y) -> int { return x + y; }
> ```
>
> Since C++11, C++ also supports closures. Closures are defined between
>   square brackets [and] in the declaration of lambda expression. The
>   mechanism allows these variables to be captured by value or by
>   reference. The following table demonstrates this:
>
> ```
> []        //no variables defined. Attempting to use any external variables in the lambda is an error.
> [x, &y]   //x is captured by value, y is captured by reference
> [&]       //any external variable is implicitly captured by reference if used
> [=]       //any external variable is implicitly captured by value if used
> [&, x]    //x is explicitly captured by value. Other variables will be captured by reference
> [=, &z]   //z is explicitly captured by reference. Other variables will be captured by value
> ```

**Résumé**

Terms *Lambda expression* and *Lambda function* are used interchangeably for signifying the definition/declaration of an anonymous function object as:

```
[capture](parameters) -> return_type { function_body }
```

With the term *closure* we refer to the run-time function object created by the evaluation of a *lambda* expression.

Now for lambdas to be evaluated at compile time, this would require a lambda to be a constant expression. Unfortunately, lambdas aren't `constexpr` and as such can't be evaluated at compile time. However, there's a proposal submitted to the committee [N4487](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4487.pdf) that suggests that with the lifting of some restrictions we could have `constexpr` lambdas. That is, in the future we might have `constexpr` lambdas that could be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expression is like other expressions, being evaluated at runtime by default. Evaluating the expression `1 + 2` gives a `int` which value is 3. Evaluating the lambda expression `[] { return 0; }` gives a closure object, which is also a function object, which `operator()()` is a function that returns 0.

In short, a closure object is a runtime object, like any other objects in C++, a lambda expression is a expression which result is a closure object.